# Hawking radiation temperature from dimensional grounds in Zee

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, temperature, dimensional-analysis, hawking-radiation

In Zee's Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell he gives an argument for the temperature of Hawking radiation of dimensional grounds only (Introduction, p 15).

It goes as follows. Both the black hole mass $M$ and the Planck mass $M_P$ have mass dimension $+1$, so one could consider a dimensionless quantity $M/M_P$. But the black hole mass only ever comes in the combination $GM$ that has dimension $-1$ so $GM/M_P$ is not dimensionless and we can ignore $M_P$. Temperature $T$ has dimension +1 so necessarily $T\propto (GM)^{-1}$.

But isn't $(GM) M_P$ dimensionless as well so we could have $T\propto (GM)^{-1}f((GM) M_P)$ for some function $f$?

This seems too simple for Zee to have it wrong so what have I missed?

Comment: It's always the case with dimensional analysis to expect functions of dimensionless paremeters dress up dimensionful quantities. Such kind of "derivations" in the introductions of textbooks are usually not meant to be taken as something else than motivations I guess. In the semi-classical setup, the temperature ends up as is known. Note that the entropy does receive corrections though, log(area) and vanshing terms 1/area

Comment: @picop That goes without saying, but it seems a bit careless  of Zee to brush this under the carpet like that.

Comment: The dimensionless quantity $(GM)M_\text{P}$ is precisely the quantity $M/M_\text{P}$, since $M_\text{P}=G^{-\frac12}$, so it could not be used as an independent dimensionless parameter.

Comment: @A.V.S. Isn't that just a circular reasoning? What prevents us from saying e.g. $T\propto GM M_P^2$? Unless of course you would claim that $M_P$ also needs to be accompanied by $G$. But why would that be the case?